# Remove middle name from full name in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I need a way to remove the middle names from my full name in SAS.

Example:
Name= MARY ANN SMITH
Name= JERRY J SMITH

Output wanted:
Name2= MARY SMITH
Name2= JERRY SMITH

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: WHat do you do if the string only contains two names?  What if it contains 4?

Comment: Add Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt and Jonathan Rhys-Davies  to your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have actual names of real people then the problem is much harder than you  implied.  Some people have first or last (or both) names that are more than one word.  What about people that only have one name?

Anyway SCAN() can do what you want.

```
name2=catx(' ',scan(name,1,' '),scan(name,-1,' '));
```